# Выведение типов аргументов дженерик метода, в теле дочернего класса

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Сложно сформулировать четкий вопрос. Проще показать на примере:
[Ссылка на TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-xB1bGbaWc8GCwY3nCyXlK328wWDNl0M16Hh1VO0NWjR0T15AkWTdI0PU2T9v1UAB5XhqV-a8NxHYCd05cCXQPA13XjaEdwAOXMMpmFXBEANvLdnkNH1lHnegjiCEJoTCLAUnAHJwkAHhBSEKQBZEEwPiK0lSp0LDICWUMH1qKHAAFSxyOTFdhnwlxPDHUDPlAMwTEsaw7B9Q0i0URQGmYJxggrMJwkAFhAMDSKJ4HCDIsngSAkgwdI0DwBzwjyGJ0EgIhDDSWB0FgQBmEAc0g0nCCBAGEQQL-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-UUUBbg7MoTrj9OBF7txAlAMJy-82BAAkQDBwBICtFsW03YXEUAizny6AEleHEJxqSevEF1n+7zc+4JT6f9pL+vlDmG7ipaD7geQ9R7j0ntPR+8dzaL2XqvCuotBZJUSuvLeO8MAhFCGAEmZNQBS0AOIghVtbkzyAUUW4tcCS1SB5VA3M06XVNpdUAp4IQNFUPPBSVoaE2xWCcN4AAWeGuhEaY1mjjOw31VCgHmqsZOlFaCMJEMw+emdwQ5zzi9AuGwYH+XgLgJKXFwhEAyrgEWGUso5Vbh3TYXce793elAixGwrF-wAW8P6g9QAjzHg0CeU9FAzzkQoy6dj1EOJFL-SoziSg8LcbQZQ+ZmBLz3vjQ+V8JDyCYSwi+KSb6sGkPfBh6T54v1NgUzJX9qRhP-jYkorigGeO8WAjh7QoErzAGzNeoBEGgE3tvUmaCgA)

Хочу сделать типизированный EventEmitter, с возможностью наследования и расширения списка типизированных событий. Но typescript вставляет "палки в колеса".

Если среди вас есть гуру typescript, пожалуйста, помогите!

```
// базовый тип списка событий
type TEventsList = Record<string, (...args: [any]) => void>;

// есть типизированный класс EventEmitter
declare class TypedEventEmitter<TEvents extends TEventsList> {
    addListener<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E, listener: TEvents[E]): this;
    on<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E, listener: TEvents[E]): this;
    once<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E, listener: TEvents[E]): this;
    removeListener<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E, listener: TEvents[E]): this;
    off<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E, listener: TEvents[E]): this;
    removeAllListeners<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E): this;
    setMaxListeners(n: number): this;
    getMaxListeners(): number;
    protectedlisteners<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E): TEvents[E][];
    rawListeners<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E): TEvents[E][];
    listenerCount<E extends keyof TEvents>(type: E): number;
    prependListener<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E, listener: TEvents[E]): this;
    prependOnceListener<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E, listener: TEvents[E]): this;
    eventNames<E extends keyof TEvents>(): Array<E>;

    // проблема с этим
    emit<E extends keyof TEvents, A extends Parameters<TEvents[E]>>(event: E, ...args: A): boolean;

    // единственный вариант сделать так, но тогда не будет работать проверка типов аргументов вызываемых событий
    // emit<E extends keyof TEvents>(event: E, ...args: any[]): boolean;
}

// события которые есть у BaseClass 
type TBaseClassEvents = {
    event1(): void;
    event2(arg1: string): void;
    event3(arg1: number, arg2: boolean): void;
}

// есть некий класс, у которого есть свои события и от которого можно унаследоваться, добавив ему дополнительные события
class BaseClass<TAdditionalEvents extends TEventsList> extends TypedEventEmitter<TAdditionalEvents & TBaseClassEvents> {
    testBaseClassMethod() {
        // проблема тут, тайпскрипт ругается
        this.emit("event2", "Hello from BaseClass"); // тут ошибка
    }
}

const baseClassInstance = new BaseClass();
baseClassInstance.emit("event2", "Hello from BaseClass"); // тут уже нет ошибки


// некий дочерний класс унаследованный от BaseClass
class ChildClass extends BaseClass<{ event4(arg1: boolean): void }> {
    testChildClassMethod() {
        // тут все прекрасно работает
        this.emit("event1");
        this.emit("event2", "Hello from ChildClass");
        this.emit("event4", true);
    }
}

const childClassInstance = new ChildClass();
childClassInstance.emit("event2", "Hello from BaseClass"); // и тут нет ошибки
```

**UPD**
Вот еще пример, для лучшего понимания проблемы
[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogNwgO2AZwDIEs3CgXigCUIBjAewCcATAHl0q2QHMAaKACgDoeBDS5mgBcUANq9kIALoBKAgD4oCclmryA3AChN1MgBt+0UgbRpY4CNUQpgcALZZgwCJVrwkqMxAAez5NTN3G0wcYEUAb00oaKhyZFo4KB8-AKgAawgQcgAzWGtPeQ4ID2AROHY9UJQXESDPUThZEWAACxwtGKSHYASk3xRUjKzcuvR2AEE+lLMABX5eOwhnSjQ3fPQGqXlC4psy9h4ufkERcZkRACNycj0ICS0AX21QSCgADQBNAC0CMWQAVzsFxc7ABQJBUDBwMoUi0mmMvFMUDgqEcIDc42o1EcWDivD06y8-X8gUJ2FwimSA0CFisJXsjmWtHCUDA5DQOLiAGEWhJmJYOOclCpqFAHlAAGSwTHY4C45D4wkRKIxMCMBC8ZxQAD6bNw8pEnx+hFEAAZ2OaoKbYdpOvy8Hq5XFBVBIp1OpQlv9KMgoK0cFxdeyncgOjEniromglqzg-KOBq9HI3e7ov60IHHfLfomw6n01wIN0OAAiPWc5A8vmWEsydRQAD0DdgAGUkpRKFRI2LNBH4SZZgYQC4ptTkajQMyWnc9K0qywBULlKoHsrOmqsBqtdrp-jWr9TXC7THd7OWi6U6nPcBvb6CzuZ608z3u9G8KfWgn8cnu517x+WhzfFnz-NoMyLRxSwA+d+WoWt6ybKAAHEAHkUIAEW7J4IwoZBcFZIcR0IZAIAAdygGZCMoQU4TAKiuGdMt2QrGCa3YF18EUXC0BuCAuD0chmFLSjeGHShY31OIoFIXkFzgmQ600OjRJcBjkCgx8WlYuD2LkTjpLiHjbn4wThKoqAAOk2TYNrRTtCAA)

Answer (score 1):

### EventTarget

EventTarget - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

```
class Q extends EventTarget { }

{//test
    const q = new Q
    q.addEventListener('qwa', () => { })
    const qwa = new Event('qwa')
    q.dispatchEvent(qwa)
}
```

## -,-

> Выведение типов аргументов дженерик метода, в теле дочернего класса

### Позиция TS.

issues/43638

> label:"Design Limitation"

### НЕ `interface`

Предлагаемое в этом ответе решение использует `export type EventsList` - это сделано не случайно. Причина в этом https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300 "Index signature is missing in type (only on interfaces, not on type alias)".

### Решение.

Есть два способа обойти проблему выведения типов при наследовании от дочернего класса:

-
`ts // -,- t1 self = this as A<B.EventsList> t1() { this.self.emit('event1', 2) }`

-
`ts // -,- t2 t2(this: A<B.EventsList>) { this.emit('event1', 2) }`

[песочница там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEVkG8BQS9IgA8YB7AJwBckKBPGZAUQDcJgKoAZASyioF4kAJQjxyAEwA8vMl2ABzADRIAFADp1IMnKgAuJCGA0A2gF0AlEj4A%20JExJcxV7AF9sYkQBtNyeF6hRUdAgJABUCQgpWMQC0DFVmVnZuXhscfAIwLgoJBnDI4GikAGsIGhIAMyQQpQBBPKiAgAVNcAhIsihQowYTKytlCBY2PQYldVVNbT0asz0AIxISDwgDF2wAenWkAFoFbY2t3f3QSFgEZDq0-CJSSmo6RiGknn4kK-S8QcSARmVgPWAAFcwHMIGRZrZ7GJcPhXK5fOgAjVQvUCkj4k9OC8bER8oVYsEQqkkK5Njs9gdycdWmdEKg3jDPsRyFRaPQkAk2FjeJYGR9rk8AEzKaR6aSyOQQuwORkkpAAMiQNQxiW5FDWCP8qBRuIaqBVXOSFBxET1yKJfPwZKO1G%20sowHkqAgoAAsePokRIUAbnilZRRfhZ3h9XTxVA7yqoIJkKMoAORfNjfONKQVmWWudLWvbUQX%204Wh3RKr0%20tVWIOy9KFqMx%20OJgMppBpjOy7P7UmHClt7CYTaRXiy0TAHmyXgGOkCYAQADuqFlo4o44gNaydaeyaU33T6QXS5XsYTQsbcYAjnH084gA)

```
namespace Base {
    export type EventsList = Record<string, (...args: any[]) => void>
}
declare class Base<T extends Base.EventsList> {
    emit<E extends keyof T, A extends Parameters<T[E]>>(event: E, ...args: A): boolean
}
// -,-
// -,-
namespace A {
    export type EventsList = {
        event1(n: number): void
    }
}
class A<T extends A.EventsList> extends Base<T> { }
// -,-
// -,-
namespace B {
    export type EventsList = {
        event2(str: string): void
    } & A.EventsList
}
class B<T extends B.EventsList> extends A<T> {
    // -,- t1
    self = this as A<B.EventsList>
    t1() {
        this.self.emit('event1', 2)
    }
    // -,- t2
    t2(this: A<B.EventsList>) {
        this.emit('event1', 2)
    }
    // -,-
}
// -,-
// -,-
{//test
    const instance = new B
    instance.emit('event1', 1)
    instance.emit('event2', 'q')
}
```

Comment: "BaseClass" это TypedEventEmitter !

В том-то и дело что нет! 
Мне нужно наследоваться от других классов, расширяя список их событий

Comment: Есть родитель, есть потомок

Comment: В вашем решении, вы во всех классах наследуетесь от класса TypedEventEmitter. Это не то что требуется. Нужна возможность наследования и расширения списка событий любых дочерних классов TypedEventEmitter.

Comment: И что? Не наследуется по моим примерам?

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Добавив туда еще один пример, для лучшего понимания проблемы

Comment: @SyaoMay, обновил ответ. Хоть я и сомневаюсь что в конкретном случае необходимо наследование от дочернего класса. Позиция TS по этому вопросу: "Design Limitation". Предлагаемое мной решение - обход проблемы.

Comment: В вашем новом решении нельзя взывать событие event1 внутри методов класс А. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEVkG8BQS9IgA8YB7AJwBckKBPGZAUQDcJgKoAZASyioF4kAJQjxyAEwA8vMl2ABzADRIAFADp1IMnKgAuJCGA0A2gF0AlEj4A+JExJcxV7AF9sYkQBtNyeF6hRUdAgJABUCQgpWMQC0DFVmVnZuXhscfAIwLgoJBnDI4GikAGsIGhIAMyQQpQBBPKiAgAVNcAhIsihQowYTKytlCBY2PQYldVVNbT0asz0AIxISDwgDF2wAenWkAFoFbY2t3f3QSFgEZDq0-CJSSmo6RiGknn4kK-S8QcSARmVgPWAAFcwHMIGRZrZ7GJcPhXK5fOgAjVQvUCkj4k9OC8bER8oVYsEQqkYXhIrwALJtAAWJDEygs7w+FCpPFUEEyFGUACIvmxvlylN8zABuJCbKoAZQIZDI5BJSDhQA)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEVkG8BQS9IgA8YB7AJwBckKBPGZAUQDcJgKoAZASyioF4kAJQjxyAEwA8vMl2ABzADRIAFADp1IMnKgAuJCGA0A2gF0AlEj4A+JExJcxV7AF9sYkQBtNyeF6hRUdAgJABUCQgpWMQC0DFVmVnZuXhscfAIwLgoJBnDI4GikAGsIGhIAMyQQpQBBPKiAgAVNcAhIsihQowYTKytlCBY2PQYldVVNbT0asz0AIxISDwgDF2wAenWkAFoFbY2t3f3QSFgEZDq0-CJSSmo6RiGknn4kK-S8QcSARmVgPWAAFcwHMIGRZrZ7GJcPhXK5fOgAjVQvUCkj4k9OC8bER8oVYsEQqkYXhIrwALJtAAWJDEygs7w+FCpPFUEEyFGUACIvmxvlylN8zABuJCbKoAZQIZDI5BJSFc6XFR2oACZ5RRVcpmTw9ASJDUMYksSkGfL0jqoGyOcoAOS8ijfW1KVVmc34S3WrJ2h1OpS21W2t3pOFAA

Comment: (C)Решение.
Есть два способа обойти проблему выведения типов при наследовании от дочернего класса: ....

Comment: Не внимательно прочитал. Извините. Решение любопытное, но не идеальное. Тем не менее. спасибо! Может когда-нибудь дизайн typescript позволит сделать то что мне нужно